# HTT, 2.2.4, Lurie

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am confused by the "canonical map of simplicial sets" mentioned  in [line 4, p88, HTT.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf). I have attached a screen shot. I would really appreciate if someone simply explain why this map exists.

[image]